# How to pass a variable to subprocess communicate

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am new to python and have done several searches on SO and google regarding this question.

How can I pass a variable pw, which is the user's password, to the input for popen.communicate?

Here is the code involved:

```
pw = getpass.getpass()
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
            ssh_conn = Popen(["ssh", "-t", server, "sudo -S cp /etc/"+map, "/etc/"+map + "." +fulltime], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
            ssh_conn.communicate(input='pw\n')[0]
```

The code above appears to send the string 'pw' to standard input, instead I would like the value of the variable pw to be sent.

I realize that this approach is less than ideal and that there are other python modules that could do the job more simply, but I am not in a position to install any additional modules.

Comment: You might want to consider using [paramiko](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paramiko/1.12.0) instead.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider changing the `sudo` configuration on your server to do something smarter than `-S` and passing the password over stdin.

Comment: @abarnet - I agree with both you and unutbu, but I am not in a position to install paramiko, it's simply not feasible. Editing the sudo configuration on the server is also not a feasible option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to insert the password into the string:

```
pw = getpass.getpass()
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
ssh_conn = Popen(["ssh", "-t", server, "sudo -S cp /etc/"+map, "/etc/"+map + "." +fulltime], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
ssh_conn.communicate(input='{0}\n'.format(pw))[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply iCodez. This error is received after making that code modification: Password:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./update_amap.py", line 65, in <module>
    main()
  File "./update_amap.py", line 63, in main
    ssh_conn.communicate(input='{}\n'.format(pw))[0]
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: @user3155618 - You must be using a Python version less than 2.7.  Try the code in my edit.

Comment: You are correct, I am using Python version 2.6.4. The edit that you provided works perfectly. Thank you and happy new year!